# nodejs memcached if one server is down, others also do not get queried

Tags: node.js, memcached

I have 2 memcached servers, and I am using memcached nodejs client.

https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached#server-locations

Now the issue is , if I stop memcached from any one server, the other server also do not get any query.
but it should save data on other servers altleast.

```
var Memcached   = require('memcached');
var memcached   = new Memcached(['127.0.0.1:11211','2nd server:11211'], {retries:0,retry:0,remove:false,failOverServers:['3rd:11211']});

// Added failure log

memcached.on('reconnecting', function( details ){ console.log( "Total downtime caused by server " + details.server + " :" + details.totalDownTime + "ms");});

memcached.on('failure', function(details) {
    console.log(new Date() + " -  - - Server " + details.server + "went down due to: " + details.messages.join( '' ) ); 
});
memcached.on('reconnecting', function(details) { 
    console.log(new Date() + " -  - - Total downtime caused by server " + details.server + " :" + details.totalDownTime + "ms");
});

memcached.on('issue', function(details) { 
    console.log(new Date() + " -  - - Server " + details.server + " has an issue: " + details.messages.join( '' ));
});
```

when I do

```
 memcached.add(key, value, expiry, function (err) { 
    if(err){
        callback(false);
    } else {    
        callback(true);
    }
 });
```

I get logs for failure server
**connect ECONNREFUSED**

but the server at localhost also do not get anything saved in cache.

also there is nothing in the memcached of 3rd server

I used this command to see what's happening

```
memcached -vv -m 1024 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -p 1121
```

I have memcached@2.2.2 node npm

and node version V6.0.0 and Linux RedHat Servers

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to connect simultaneously to two Memcached servers, most likely for load-balancing purposes. Memcached will store some of the keys on one server and the rest on the other, therefore depending on both.

The first parameter to the Memcached constructor defines either a single string, array of strings or objects and then the library attempts to connect to all of them simultaneously.
This is not the as the later defined `failOverServers` array, which the application can live without.

Therefore the error in your code is the invalid definition of the second instance, namely

```
'2nd server:11211'
```

This is an invalid URL and therefore Memcached will fail to connect to this 'server', thus throwing a **ECONNREFUSED** error.

Simply remove this second instance from the array and modify the line to:

```
new Memcached('127.0.0.1:11211', {/* ... */});
```

*Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached#user-content-setting-up-the-client*

Comment: Thanks for answering @kGrozdanovski , but I have written '2nd server' in my code , because I didn't want to share the IP of the 2nd server, publically. Anyways, this was resolved a long ago in 2017. I don't excatly remember the root cause right now.Thanks Again.